# JavaScript matching domains and partial

Tags: javascript

```
var url = 'http://sub.domain2.net/contact/';

if (['https://sub.domain1.com/', 'http://sub.domain2.net/'].indexOf(url) > -1) {
    console.log('match');
} else {
    console.log('no match');
}
```

In the above it checks whether the `url` matches any of the 2 in my array. Only I want it to partial match the domain.

The url `http://sub.domain2.net/contact/` should match the tld in my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var url = 'http://sub.domain2.net/contact/';

var didMatch = ['https://sub.domain1.com/', 'http://sub.domain2.net/'].some(function(u) {
    return url.indexOf(u) !== -1;
});

if (didMatch) {
    console.log('match');
} else {
    console.log('no match');
}
```

Replace `url.indexOf(u)` with `url.startsWith(u)` if you only want to check against the starting of the urls in the array.

If you want to support <IE9, use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the problem in wrong direction. If all TLDs would be same length, you could cut the `url` at same length to use in `indexOf`. Otherwise, you need to use a loop, and `startsWith` function to do it.